# When exporting a layout in ArcGIS Pro, the colours show as grey when they should not be. How do I fix this?

Tags: arcgis-pro, export, layouts, color

I have a layout in ArcGIS Pro which shows a Hot Spot Analysis Comparison output. When exporting the layout, the colours on the map do not show - they appear as grey instead. How do I rectify this issue? I have tried exporting the layer as a PNG, JPEG, SVG and PDF. I am using V3.1 of ArcGIS Pro.

The only possible solution I have found online is deleting the map and starting again, but this is not an option for me given the amount of data.

Comment: Is it just the hotspot colours, or is it everything on the map?

Comment: Maybe it's related to color management setting ? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/color-management-application-settings.htm